# How to make a multiple update on mysql with string replace with value of another column

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i'm new in mysql and i have to run a multiple update on my table.
I have 700 records in the table and i have to update them all this way:

table example :
store_id: 1
store_email: storename@gmail.com

for single update i use

```
UPDATE stores SET email = '1@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1;
```

i need to update all the emails and replace their name with their id, so it would be like this:

storename@gmail.com --> 1@gmail.com

storename@gmail.com --> 2@gmail.com

storename@gmail.com --> 3@gmail.com

those numers have to be the ID for each store.

Hope you can understand

Thanks for help.

P.S. i need to run it on magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `CONCAT()` and `RIGHT()` function for manipulating strings like this:

```
UPDATE stores SET email = CONCAT(id, RIGHT(email, 9));
```

The `RIGHT('string', n)` function extracts n characters (storemail = 9 chars in your case) from a string (starting from right).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding id to String column gmail, you can use contact() fucntion like below :

```
  UPDATE stors SET email=CONCAT(id, "@gmail.com") where id=2;
```